# Oracle 12 - Reporting on Roles

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, reporting, audit

Is there a way to report on all the custom roles and/or responsibilities created within Oracle, Outside of SQL?

I am looking for a dashboard that shows how many have x role, y role that could be sent to senior level management.

Comment: you may use spooling feature of SQL*PLUS and execute `SQL>SELECT * FROM DBA_ROLES;`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list all the roles of a particular user:

```
select granted_role,admin_option,default_role from dba_role_privs where grantee='&user';
```

If you want to list all users with all roles assigned:

```
select b.username,a.granted_role,a.admin_option,a.default_role from dba_role_privs a join dba_users b on (a.grantee=b.username);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I use toad for a lot of what I pull but was looking for something more "user friendly" for Sr. Management. Anything available at all that can take this data and populate it into a dashboard? I know it's a stretch but I thought I would ask.